# Load list of active users from database with symfony without using a controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I'm making a presonification menu on my navbar so that i can access from any page i don't want to use the getRepository inside a controller and pass to the frontend.

Is there a way on symfony 4 that I can get all the users from my database and call it to front? like the `app.session.user` (to get info on the logged user) for example?

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a navbar on multiple pages, in which you want to display data from the database, but you don't want to call the Repository in every Controller ? Did I understand correctly ?

Comment: An [embedded controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers) is one approach.

Comment: Why not use a service to achieve this, and inject that service into your controller? This would also allow that stuff to be tested - on the other hand, why not implement a simple getter method for this in your repository, and inject the repository in the controller? Is there any downside?

Comment: exactly Victor.
Thanks Cerad, gonna check on that, but it doesn't have a "simpler" way, like the app.session example?

Comment: Nico, the problem is that I want to be able to access the list from any page, so i'm rendering it on my base twig file that it's on every page of my system.

Comment: The embedded controller approach not only allows you to do your database queries but it can take of rendering the results for you.  In that sense it is pretty simple.  But you can also checkout how to define your own twig globals (which is what app.session is) or you could look at making a twig extension.  All three approaches have their usages and all are worth knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cerad mentioned, you can embed a Controller in your templates : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers

Instead of doing `{% include 'base/navbar.html.twig' %}` you will do

**In your template :**

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\BaseController::renderNavbar')) }}
```

**In BaseController**

```
public function renderNavbar(UserRepository $userRepository) {
    return $this->render('base/navbar.html.twig', [
        'activeUsers' => $userRepository->findActiveUsers(),
    ]);
}
```

It's not a route, it's simply a function that renders html, so you don't need to add annotations.

Comment: Thanks very much, you and Cerad. It worked, the only thing I needed to do was create a different template so i could render it on my base template.